# Streaming already segmented and stored m3u8 playlist file from Wowza VODS3

Tags: wowza, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I have a VODS3 application setup, from which I can stream through

RTSP
RTMP
HTTP

Protocols easily.

I want to do something different:

In case of HTTP protocol, right now I have this URL (example):

```
http://[ip]:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/mys3bucket/vid.MP4/playlist.m3u8
```

Which play fine.

Now, I do not want Wowza to make variants of vid.MP4 and serve me through http protocol, I want to create segmented files myself and store them and the playlist on s3 bucket.

For example, the playlist I have on S3 is something like:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:10.006667,
vc_49520_out0.ts
#EXTINF:10.006667,
vc_49520_out1.ts
#EXTINF:10.006667,
vc_49520_out2.ts
#EXTINF:10.006667,
vc_49520_out3.ts
#EXTINF:1.267511,
vc_49520_out4.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Saved as "vc_49520_out.m3u8" inside the bucket, and, all dependent files:

```
vc_49520_out0.ts
vc_49520_out1.ts
vc_49520_out2.ts
vc_49520_out3.ts
vc_49520_out4.ts
```

are also stored on S3.

I want to give this link to the player, and, want Wowza to start streaming based on the playlist 'already' stored.

Something like:

```
http://[ip]:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/mys3bucket/vc_49520_out.m3u8
```

But, this does not seem to work.

Anyway I can get the stream this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not think wowza support static (pre-created) m3u8 files.

https://www.wowza.com/community/questions/7171/stream-pre-created-ts-chunks-using-static-m3u8-pla.html

I know that you can create an smil file, probably you can do what you want with the smil file. Then you can call it like this ( please note the "*smil:"* prefix):

```
http://[wowza-ip-address]/vod/smil:sample.smil/playlist.m3u8
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I cannot do SMIL as I am doing none of the following: trans-rating/trans-sizing etc. I have my files already stored in MP4 format in an AWS S3 bucket, and using VODS3 application (Wowza), i can playback using RTMP/RTSP links mentioned with original post, but I get choppy playback which is not desired...

Answer (score 0):

As you already have created (maybe using [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org), [Bitmovin](https://bitmovin.com/cloud-encoding-service/) or Zencoder) what Wowza would generate usually on-the-fly, you don't need Wowza at all in this set up. You could use the S3 public link directly or, for better performance, add a CDN, such as [Akamai](https://www.akamai.com), [Limelight](https://www.limelight.com), [Level3](http://www.level3.com) or [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/),  in front of S3.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; I tried to setup CloudFront on top of S3, and it works. Only concern was the 'public' access, as I want to restrict access to some users only. Tutorials on top of CloudFront got me to the extent I felt I had the option to use JW Player/ and some other player. I do not want to use JW other other player (as of now), as I already have a player implementation on top of libav (FFmpeg base library).